# How do I enable "Desktop Slideshow" with Powershell only?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

How do I change the setting in **Settings App > Personalization > Background** so that it uses one of the three selections with PowerShell.  I just want it to change the **Background** setting **only**, not alter the existing settings or change the background in the background that is controlled by a script.  So far I see things where people use powershell to change the background image, but not just control that one setting.

[image]

Comment: Please check if this can answer you: [Set Windows 10 background slideshow script in Powershell](https://girts.niedra.org/2020/02/set-windows-10-background-slideshow-script-in-powershell/)

Comment: I tried that one it just seems either set only one background and the next background option does not appear on the desktop.